# Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on Surface 3 Pro - Touchpad 2-finger-gestures

Tags: 16.04, touchpad, multi-touch, surface

I'm running Kubuntu 16.04 with the newest kernel on my SP3. Everything works fine except the touchpad, there is no option to activate two-finger-scrolling and 2-finger-tap-right-click.

I've found that source, but it seems to be on 4.3. and I'm using 4.6.x.!

https://launchpad.net/~tigerite/+archive/ubuntu/kernel?field.series_filter=xenial

But maybe someone have already tried it and could tell me, whether the touchpad works with 2-finger-scrolling?

Any other suggestions? Could someone help me?

Comment: What touchpad are you using? With synaptic touchpads you should may be able to do it - what is the output of `synclient -l`?

Comment: I'm using the Type Cover 3. Everything works fine, but in System Settings > Input Devices it says that no synaptics backend is found. `synclient -l` says `Couldn't find synaptics properties. No synaptics driver loaded?`.